# How can I create a label inside a ViewCell that when clicked will call a method?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
<ViewCell x:Name="ss" Height="50">
    <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
        <Label Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Category Group" />
        <Switch x:Name="ssSwitch" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1" Toggled="SsSwitch" />
    </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

I would like to extend this with another row and a label with the text of "Clear Deck"

How can I add a label for this that when clicked will call a method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple example of how to do it. You just need to add a Label with a `TapGestureRecognizer`. Then you need to implement `ClearLabelTapped` in the code behind.

```
<ViewCell x:Name="ss" Height="50">
  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
      <Label Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Category Group" />
      <Switch x:Name="ssSwitch" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1" Toggled="SsSwitch" />
    </Grid>
    <Label Text="Clear Deck">
      <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ClearLabelTapped" />
      </Label.GestureRecognizers>
    </Label>
  </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

Code behind:

```
public void ClearLabelTapped(object sender, EventArgs args) 
{
   // This is called when you tab the "Clear Deck" label
}
```

Please notice that using view models and commands would be a better way to do this (separation of concerns) but I wanted to keep this simple. Refer to the official documentation on [how to work with the TapGestureRecognizer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap/#Using_ICommand).